# R: Efficient Way to Merge+Update Table With Second Table Where Values from Same Column Names Fill NAs

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

**Summary**: I would like to merge two tables by shared `id` key as `all=true` (full outer join) where instead of columns with the same names being set as `var1.x` `var2.y`, etc., they are merged as a single column where missing (NA) values in the left table are filled in by values from the right table (in addition to the standard behavior of merge, i.e., appending rows with distinct ids and columns with distinct names).

**Details:**

I would like to merge + update `table1` with `table2` based on a shared `id` key column such that:

1) If `table1` and `table2` have columns with the same name (other than `id`), the value in `table1` is left alone if it exists and replaced by the value in `table2` if the value in `table1` is NA.

2) If table2 has columns that table1 does not have (different names), they are merged (by id).

3) If `table1` has an `id` that does not match in `table2`, values for different name columns from `table2` are NA

4) If `table2` has an `id` that does not match in `table1`, it is added as a new row and the values for the different column names from `table1` are NA.

3 & 4 are as with standard `merge` with `all=TRUE`.

I'm concerned that I have overthought the problem as I cannot find a straightforward way to do this with a `merge` or `join` that doesn't involve creating `ifelse` checks on every column.  Real data has ~1000 columns, so would be incredibly long solution to do `ifelse` lookups on each one.

Reproducible reduced example:

```
table1  <- data.table(id  =c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6"),
                      var1=c(1,2,3,4,5, 6),
                      var2=c("a", "b", NA, "d", NA, "f"),
                      var3=c(NA, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16));

table2  <- data.table(id  =c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id8"),
                      var1=c(1,2,NA,4,5, 8),
                      var2=c(NA, "b", "c", "d", "e", "h"),
                      var4=c("foo", "bar", "oof", "rab", NA, "sna"));

desired <- data.table(id=c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", "id8"),
                      var1=c(1,2,3,4,5, 6, 8),
                      var2=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h"),
                      var3=c(NA, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, NA),
                      var4=c("foo", "bar", "oof", "rab", NA, NA, "sna"));

table1;
    id var1 var2 var3
1: id1    1    a   NA
2: id2    2    b   12
3: id3    3   NA   13
4: id4    4    d   14
5: id5    5    e   15
6: id6    6    f   16

table2;
    id var1 var2 var4
1: id1    1    a  foo
2: id2    2    b  bar
3: id3   NA    c  oof
4: id4    4    d  rab
5: id5    5    e   NA
6: id8    8    h  sna

desired
    id var1 var2 var3 var4
1: id1    1    a   NA  foo
2: id2    2    b   12  bar
3: id3    3    c   13  oof
4: id4    4    d   14  rab
5: id5    5    e   15   NA
6: id6    6    f   16   NA
7: id8    8    h   NA  sna
```

Explanation of desired output:

1. For column `var1`, `table1` had all the values, so it is left alone and the `NA` for `id3` in `table2` is ignored (note that this doesn't include the row merge for different ids described below).
2. For column `var2`, `table` was missing the value indexed by `id3`, so it is updated from `table2` (note that this doesn't include the row merge for different ids described below).
3. For column `var3`, there is no matching column in `table2`, so it is kept as is.
4. For column `var4`, there was no column `var4` in `table1`, so it is merged from `table2` by `id` key variable.
5. For row with `id6` in `table1`, there is no matching `id6` in `table2`, so the value for column `var4` that is only in `table2` is NA in the `desired` output for row `id6`.
6. For row with `id8` in `table2` there is no matching `id8` in `table1`, so the value for column `var3` that is only in `table1` is NA in the `desired` output for row `id8`.

Surely there is a straightforward way to do this with `data.table`?  Efficient solutions are particularly welcome given the size of the real data.  The `datamerge` package apparently used to do exactly this, but it isn't on CRAN anymore and I can't get it to work on R3.2.3 from zip.  Has another package stepped up for this task?  There are many other threads that focus on solving this for a one or a couple of columns with known names, but for large number of columns, they don't seem practical.

Comment: The set of `id`s is the same in both tables and each `id` only appears on one row?

Comment: @Frank Good question.  Not the same in both tables, yes appears on one row in each.  Updating reduced example to include that information.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I think your stipulation #6 has a typo. Should say "only in `table2`"

Comment: @Frank I wasn't very clear with 5 & 6. I've clarified it now.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I've now clarified #1 & #2 to explain that I'm talking just about the update/replace, not the merge (with rows with new ids) that are explained in parts 5 & 6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
com.cols    = setdiff(intersect(names(table1), names(table2)), "id")
com.cols.x  = paste0(com.cols, ".x")
com.cols.y  = paste0(com.cols, ".y")

# create combined table
DT = setkey(merge(table1, table2, by="id", all=TRUE), NULL)

# edit common columns where NAs are present
for (j in seq_along(com.cols)) 
  DT[is.na(get(com.cols.x[j])), (com.cols.x[j]) := get(com.cols.y[j])]

# remove unneeded columns
DT[, (com.cols.y) := NULL]

# rename kept columns
setnames(DT, com.cols.x, com.cols)

identical(DT, desired) # TRUE
```

It's rather messy to create and work with all these column-names vectors.

---

**Regarding the original question...**

Here's another way (without importing new rows from `table2`, as in the original post):

```
com.cols    = setdiff(intersect(names(table1), names(table2)), "id")
i.com.cols  = paste0("i.", com.cols)
new.cols    = c(i.com.cols, setdiff(names(table2), c("id", com.cols)))

# grab columns from table2
table1[table2, (new.cols) := mget(new.cols), on="id"]

# edit common columns where NAs are present
for (j in seq_along(com.cols)) 
  table1[is.na(get(com.cols[j])), (com.cols[j]) := get(i.com.cols[j])]

# remove unneeded columns
table1[, (i.com.cols) := NULL]
```

This way all steps are modifications of `table1` by reference.

Comment: Very nice. Is there a reason you do `table1[table2, (new.cols) := mget(new.cols), on="id"]` rather than `table1[table2, on="id"]` ?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks. This way, I don't have to create a new table; I'm just adding column pointers to the existing table.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option that avoids explicitly adding the `i.` columns to the original table:

```
com.cols    = setdiff(intersect(names(table1), names(table2)), "id")
i.com.cols  = paste0("i.", com.cols)
# I'm using the same var names as Frank, but new.cols is strictly the new ones here
new.cols    = setdiff(names(table2), names(table1))

# this is easy - the previously absent cols
table1[table2, (new.cols) := mget(new.cols), on = 'id']

# now for the ones that need updating
table1[table2, on = 'id',
       (com.cols) := Map(function(col, i.col) pmin(col, i.col, na.rm = T),
                         mget(com.cols), mget(i.com.cols))]
```

I have no idea which option is faster - OP can check that.

Comment: `pmin` has to be faster, than the previous `mapply` version, but I'm fairly certain Frank's method is going to be faster

Comment: I guess `pmin` will behave strangely for factors (since their min is not well-defined), but I guess similar `factor`-related problems apply to all the answers. (It's not clear the range of columns the OP might have in those hundreds and hundreds of cols.)

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT: Quick adjustment

Do this first to get all the necessary rows:

```
table1 <- table1[.(id = union(id, table2$id)), on = "id"]
```

---

I don't like `mget`, so I propose the following:

```
in_common <- parse(text=setdiff(intersect(names(table1), names(table2)), "id"))

for (ii in in_common)
  table1[is.na(eval(ii)), 
         as.character(ii) :=
           table2[.SD, eval(ii), on = "id"]]
```

The new columns are easy:

```
new_cols <- setdiff(names(table2), names(table1))

for (jj in new_cols)
  table1[table2, (jj) := eval(parse(text = jj)), on = "id"]
```

I suppose it's even faster to do something like:

```
in_common_c <- setdiff(intersect(names(table1), names(table2)), "id"))
in_common_q <- parse(text=in_common_c)

for (ii in seq_along(in_common_q))
  table1[is.na(eval(in_common_q[ii])), 
         in_common_c[ii] :=
           table2[.SD, eval(in_common_q[ii]), on = "id"]]
```

But I hope the difference is marginal.

Comment: I don't like `mget` too, but I prefer using language objects, kind of `as.call(c(list(as.name(":="), new_cols), lapply(.)))`. I also don't like `parse` even more than `mget` :P